# Razor C# - Setting up checkbox values

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have my form with my checkbox inputs, and user can edit that. I can save these values in database good, but I don't know how to refill the form, so user can edit it.

This is my ViewBag var:

```
 ViewBag.NewFriends = preferences.NewFriends;// this value is a boolean, false
```

I try to pre-set values like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SavePreferences", "Conta"))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)
    @Html.CheckBox("newFriends", new { @checked = @ViewBag.NewFriends })
    @Html.Label("newFriends", "Solicitações de Amigo de Alma")
    <p><input type="submit" value="Send" /></p>
}
```

As HTML checkbox has the value checked="checked", and not true or false, it doesn't work.
@Html.CheckBox has the first parameter as input name, and second a boolean checked(true or false).

My question is how can I easily set up this value? I tried:

```
@Html.CheckBox("newFriends", ViewBag.NewFriends) // where ViewBag.NewFriends = false
```

But it doesn't work at all...

Any idea?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Probably extension method `CheckBox` can't work with dynamic. I tried following example and it works:

```
@{ bool isNewFriends =  ViewBag.NewFriends; }
@Html.CheckBox("newFriends", isNewFriends);
```